# How do I set the value for Serial/Lot Number on an Inventory Detail Subrecord?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have tried everything to get this working but no matter what I do, I always get the following error from NetSuite:

```
error code: USER_ERROR error message: {"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"USER_ERROR","message":"Please enter value(s) for: Serial/Lot Number","stack":["anonymous(N/serverRecordService)"...
```

This occurs when I try to commit the line.

What I am attempting to do (in a RESTlet) is programatically create a Work Order Completion (WOC) for an existing Work Order (WO).  I have it working for the first operation.  However, for the final operation, which requires an Inventory Detail, I am getting the error.  Here is my code (I have removed error checking, etc for better clarity):

```
/**
* @NApiVersion 2.x
* @NScriptType restlet
*/
define(['N/runtime', 'N/error', 'N/record', 'N/search'], function(runtime, error, record, search) {

  return {
    get : function(datain) {

        var wo = record.load({
            type: record.Type.WORK_ORDER,
            id: datain.woid
        });

        var woc = record.transform({
            fromType: record.Type.WORK_ORDER,
            fromId: datain.woid,
            toType: record.Type.WORK_ORDER_COMPLETION,
            isDynamic: true,
            defaultValues: {
              isbackflush: 'F',
            }
        });
        woc.setText({
            fieldId: "startoperation",
            text: "20"
        });
        woc.setText({
            fieldId: "endoperation",
            text: "20"
        });
        woc.setText({
            fieldId: "completedquantity",
            text: "230"
        });

        var invdetail = woc.getSubrecord({
          fieldId: "inventorydetail"
        });

        invdetail.selectNewLine({
          sublistId: "inventoryassignment",
        });
        invdetail.setCurrentSublistValue({
          sublistId: "inventoryassignment",
          fieldId: "binnumber",
          value: 29
        });
        invdetail.setCurrentSublistValue({
          sublistId: "inventoryassignment",
          fieldId: "quantity",
          value: 230
        });
        invdetail.setCurrentSublistText({
          sublistId: "inventoryassignment",
          fieldId: "issueinventorynumber",
          text: "abc"
        });
        invdetail.commitLine({
          sublistId: "inventoryassignment",
        });

        woc.save();

        var results = {
            woc: woc
        };

        return JSON.stringify(results);
    }
  }
});
```

I have tried everything I can think of.  Using setCurrentSublistValue() and setCurrentSublistText(), setting the value to an existing lot, new lot, etc, etc.

However, no matter what I do, NS always responds with the "Please enter value(s) for: Serial/Lot Number" error as if it is not set.

Thoughts, ideas, suggestions???

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `receiptinventorynumber` for your fieldId.

```
invdetail.setCurrentSublistValue({
                    sublistId: 'inventoryassignment',
                    fieldId: 'receiptinventorynumber',
                    value: 'lotNumber'
                });
invdetail.commitLine({sublistId: 'inventoryassignment'});
```

Comment: Yes! That worked.  Thanks @ehcanadian     Can you explain why it has to be `receiptinventorynumber` instead of `issueinventorynumber`?  Especially since the schema browser shows `issueinventorynumber`.   I am VERY appreciative for your help!

Comment: @MarkFord `receiptinventorynumber` is for increasing inventory, while `issueInventorynumber` is for decreasing inventory. I wondered the same thing at one time, and I believe something in SA led me to learn this.

Comment: That makes sense.  I am just now starting our interface work with NS.  Most of working with SuiteScript and NS is pretty straightforward, but there are lots of hidden, or at the very least, obscure landmines like this that can really be frustrating.  Again, thanks so much!

Comment: i am getting an error:  

Please enter value(s) for: Bin  

Any idea what could be the reason?